# An ASP.NET MVC validator to make sure at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, dto

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 project in which I've created a data transfer object to receive data from a web page form. The form has two groups of checkboxes on it. I want to validate the object to make sure that at least one of the checkboxes in each group is checked.

I'm doing the validation on the server side so that a user won't be able to hack around any client-side validation. (I will add client-side validation with jQuery later; that's easy.)

My understanding is that I have to create my own custom ValidationAttribute for my data transfer object class, but I don't understand how to create and use one that can accept an arbitrary list of checkbox properties to make sure that at least one of them is true. I am guessing I will have to call the attributes like this:

```
[AtLeastOneCheckbox("set1check1", "set1check2", "set1check3",
    ErrorMessage = "You must check at least one checkbox in set 1.")]
[AtLeastOneCheckbox("set2check1", "set2check2", "set2check3", "set2check4", "set2check5",
    ErrorMessage = "You must check at least one checkbox in set 2.")]
public class MyFormDTO
{
    ...
}
```

What would the implementation of AtLeastOneCheckboxAttribute look like?

Or is there a different way that I should do this kind of validation?

Comment: In addition, I'm wondering why Microsoft MVC is pushing me into this 'attribute' validation system for everything. If I use the checks done by the RequiredAttribute and StringLengthAttribute and other validation attributes I place on each property, and then I also add an IsValid() method to my object which does other checks on the properties on this object to decide whether it's valid, is there a way to have the ModelState reflect the result of my IsValid() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**if you have several checkbox groups, you just need to deine the attribute several times.**

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class AtLeastOneCheckboxAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private string[] _checkboxNames;

    public AtLeastOneCheckboxAttribute(params string[] checkboxNames)
    {
        _checkboxNames = checkboxNames;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyInfos = value.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x=>_checkboxNames.Contains(x.Name));

        var values = propertyInfos.Select(x => x.GetGetMethod().Invoke(value, null));
        if (values.Any(x => Convert.ToBoolean(x)))
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage = "At least one checkbox must be selected";
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

as  you have found out, class-level validation is called only after all properties pass. In order to get the error, **just use empty string as the key**.

Comment: I tried using your code, but it doesn't seem to be called. I'm setting the AtLeastOneCheckboxAttribute on my object and then checking ModelState in the controller, but the IsValid() method of this attribute is never being called, even though my RequiredAttributes and StringLengthAttributes are properly generating error messages. Also - how would I get the validation message from this into my view? <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Set1Check1) %>, or something like that?

Comment: Found a solution to the first half of my question - apparently class-level attributes aren't called unless all of the property-level attributes pass. I can live with that. But I'm still trying to work out how to get this attribute's error message into the view...

Comment: If I'm defining two attributes, one for each set of checkboxes, then how do I get the error for each specific set of checkboxes? Instead of using the empty string as the key, how do I set a specific key to use? This does not appear to work: return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new List<string>() { "Set1Check1" });

Comment: There seems to be a bug or limitation with returning validation result and the error does not seem to be used. Just set the ErrorMessage as per my implementation. Anyway, object will be invalid until all is valid and I think errors will be concatenated.

Comment: How to use this solution, where do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Your DTO, which is I'm guessing your ViewModel can ihert IDataErrorInfo.
Then you can do your validation like this (note I didn't compile this)

```
//I'm guessing you have a list of checkboxes
IEnumerable<bool> checkBoxes1;
IEnumerable<bool> checkBoxes2;

public class MyFormDTO : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string this[string prop]
    {
        get
        {
            if(prop == "checkBoxes1")
            {
                if(checkBoxes1.Any(x => x == true))
                {
                    return "Error: You need to select atleast one checkbox from set1";
                }
            }
            else if(prop == "checkBoxes2")
            {
                if(checkBoxes2.Any(x => x == true))
                {
                    return "Error: You need to select atleast one checkbox from set2";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    public string Error { get { return null; } }
}
```