# MVC 3 Checkbox Valdaition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
       public bool SingleFamily { get; set; }

       public bool Condominium { get; set; }

       public bool Townhouse { get; set; }
   }
```

Below is my view:

```
        <p>
            @Html.Label("Property Type")
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SingleFamily)
            <label>Single Family</label>
            <br />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Townhouse)
            <label>Townhouse</label>
            <br />
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Condominium)
            <label>Condominium</label>
        </p>
```

I would like to make sure that at least one checkbox is checked before the user submits the form. Also I would like to have the validation both on the server and the client side. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491521/an-asp-net-mvc-validator-to-make-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need a custom validator

See http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2 for a good example