# showing error message from a custom validator or MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side, customvalidator

i'm using this solution [An ASP.NET MVC validator to make sure at least one checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491521/an-asp-net-mvc-validator-to-make-sure-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked) to have at least one checkbox checked on my form. But i can't figure out how to display the error message, in unobstrusive.

I suppose i should use a ValidationMessageFor with a custom script for the client side.

Comment: This helped me when I was doing a similar thing: [http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/22/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/22/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-ii-client-code.aspx)

Comment: One of the thing i don't understand, is how i'm supposed to show the validation message. Usualy i use a ValidationMessageFor with the name of the propertie. But this time, my validator is not bound to a property, but independant and verifying several properties

Comment: If you look at the [first part](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx) of the guide I linked to, you'll see that the property that needs to be validated is given the custom attribute [GreaterThan]. In the 2nd part you can see how the attribute implements IClientValidatable for use unobtrusively, then there is script to add to jQuery.validator so jquery knows what message to show.

Comment: You can use @html.ValidationMessage("ErrorMessage"). When your page is rendered, it will display whatever message that is stored in the variable "ErrorMEssage"